# MQTT subscribe on messageArrived

Tags: android, mqtt

I'm developing and Android app in Java and I'm trying to subscribe to a new topic once I receive some message on the `messageArrived` callback, but the subscribe method is not returning. The client is connected.

I'm using the synchronous (blocking) MqttClient version.

I tried to disconnect and connect again but I get "Disconnecting is not allowed from a callback method", so I'm guessing that with the subscribe method it's similar.

So the question is, How can I subscribe to another topic on `messageArrived` event? Or, how can I reconnect on `messageArrived` event?

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Can you post some example code? Also you really shouldn't be doing network IO on the callback thread, it's better to hand it off to a separate queue handled by a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably specific to the API you are using but in general, if you are making a blocking call from the IO thread, you are blocking the thread that would normally receive the response used to unblock the calling thread.

Explanation:

> Let's say you have two threads:
>
> Thread 1 : Application thread.
>
> Thread 2 : IO thread.
>
> --- Actions
>
> Thread 1: connect() (blocking)
>
> Thread 2: Receive CONNACK (unblock thread 1)
>
> Thread 1: subscribe("topic1") (blocking)
>
> Thread 2: Receive SUBACK (unblock thread 1)
>
> Thread 2: Receive message (which in your case triggers a blocking subscribe)
>
> Since Thread 2 is blocked waiting on a SUBACK packet, it cannot read
>   from the socket to receive the SUBACK packet.

I can think of two solutions:

1) Use a non-blocking subscribe from the IO thread (and handle asynchronous confirmation)

2) Dispatch blocking subscribe() to a different thread.